# C#, How to use an external file as an optional module?

Tags: c#, .net, module, external, windows

Here's the story of my question:

I have a .Net (C#) windows application. This app contains a Panel, a Drop Down and a button.

There's a folder named `plugins` near my executable file (winapp...exe) which i wish it contains my custom program module files. Like (add2digit.moduleextention, add3digit.moduleextention, addNdigit.moduleextention, ...).List of these files will be shown in my drop down. All these custom module files need to be written in C#, and all have to implement an interface contains one methods { panel:: GetGUI() };

When i change the drop down, i wish to load the selected  module GUI into the panel using it's GetUI() method. By this manner i wont need to recompile my code if i developed further modules. Please give me some keywords or solutions which help me figure this problem out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create an `Interface` with `GetUI()` and other methods declared in it and implement that in plugins, then in your main application you should do something like this:

```
using System.Reflection;
// ...
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file);
yourInterface plugin = (yourInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(assembly));
// ...
plugin.GetUI(); // or whatever
```

Comment: So what type of file should be my plugin file? Can i use .dll files?

Comment: I'd say that the dll files are the most logical if not the only choice here.